# Multiple single image tilesets not rendering on map display

Tags: java, libgdx, tiled

I've created a map in tiled with 5 seperate tilesets
Four of these are object layers with a single image in a tileset so they can be resized

The Tile layer works as expected including loading its tileset but none of the object layers are displaying though logging from the assetmanager displays that they have been loaded successfully

This is my tmx file with the base64 encoded string removed for brevity

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<map version="1.5" tiledversion="1.7.2" orientation="orthogonal" renderorder="left-up" width="100" height="200" tilewidth="32" tileheight="32" infinite="0" nextlayerid="21" nextobjectid="11">
 <tileset firstgid="1" source="Background.tsx"/>
 <tileset firstgid="2" source="CaveEntrance.tsx"/>
 <tileset firstgid="4" source="CaveEntranceForeground.tsx"/>
 <tileset firstgid="5" source="gather_terrains_3.x.tsx"/>
 <tileset firstgid="7845" source="Fossil.tsx"/>
 <layer id="14" name="Tile Layer 2" width="100" height="200">
  <properties>
   <property name="isForeground" type="bool" value="false"/>
  </properties>
  <data encoding="base64" compression="zlib">
base64compressedstring
  </data>
 </layer>
 <objectgroup id="15" name="Background">
  <properties>
   <property name="isForeground" type="bool" value="false"/>
  </properties>
  <object id="1" name="Background" gid="1" x="0" y="1600" width="3196" height="1604"/>
 </objectgroup>
 <objectgroup id="18" name="CaveForeground">
  <properties>
   <property name="isForeground" type="bool" value="true"/>
  </properties>
  <object id="4" gid="4" x="0" y="1760" width="556" height="439"/>
 </objectgroup>
 <objectgroup id="17" name="CaveBackground">
  <properties>
   <property name="isForeground" type="bool" value="false"/>
  </properties>
  <object id="3" gid="3" x="0" y="1762" width="556" height="439"/>
 </objectgroup>
 <objectgroup id="19" name="Fossil">
  <properties>
   <property name="isForeground" type="bool" value="false"/>
  </properties>
  <object id="5" gid="7845" x="107" y="2339" width="128" height="125"/>
  <object id="6" gid="7845" x="1268" y="2651" width="128" height="125"/>
  <object id="7" gid="7845" x="2290.55" y="3823.61" width="128" height="125"/>
  <object id="8" gid="7845" x="260.242" y="4093.3" width="128" height="125"/>
  <object id="9" gid="7845" x="1669.33" y="5566.03" width="128" height="125"/>
  <object id="10" gid="7845" x="2684.48" y="6275.12" width="128" height="125"/>
 </objectgroup>
</map>
```

This is one of the object tsx files, they are all basically the same with minor differences in size and texture used

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<tileset version="1.5" tiledversion="1.7.2" name="CaveEntranceBackground" tilewidth="556" tileheight="439" tilecount="1" columns="0">
 <grid orientation="orthogonal" width="1" height="1"/>
 <tile id="1">
  <image width="556" height="439" source="CaveEntranceBack.png"/>
 </tile>
</tileset>
```

I have the map (tmx file) and all the assets (tsx and bitmap) stored in a single directory `/assets/maps/`

This is the output from the assetmanager

```
[AssetManager] Loading: maps/TheVault.tmx, com.badlogic.gdx.maps.tiled.TiledMap
[AssetManager] Loading dependency: maps/game_background.png, com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture
[AssetManager] Loading dependency: maps/CaveEntranceBack.png, com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture
[AssetManager] Loading dependency: maps/CaveEntranceFront.png, com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture
[AssetManager] Loading dependency: maps/gather_terrains_3.a.png, com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture
[AssetManager] Loading dependency: maps/fossil.png, com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture
[diagnostics] maps/gather_terrains_3.a.png, Texture, refs: 1
maps/CaveEntranceBack.png, Texture, refs: 1
maps/CaveEntranceFront.png, Texture, refs: 1
maps/TheVault.tmx, TiledMap, refs: 1, deps: [maps/game_background.png,maps/CaveEntranceBack.png,maps/CaveEntranceFront.png,maps/gather_terrains_3.a.png,maps/fossil.png,]
maps/game_background.png, Texture, refs: 1
maps/fossil.png, Texture, refs: 1
[assetnames] maps/gather_terrains_3.a.png,maps/CaveEntranceBack.png,maps/CaveEntranceFront.png,maps/TheVault.tmx,maps/game_background.png,maps/fossil.png
```

I'm loading the map with

```
manager = new AssetManager();
        Logger log = new Logger("AssetManager", Application.LOG_DEBUG);
        manager.setLogger(log);
        manager.setLoader(TiledMap.class, new TmxMapLoader(new InternalFileHandleResolver()));
        manager.load("maps/TheVault.tmx", TiledMap.class);

        manager.finishLoading();

        map = manager.get("maps/TheVault.tmx", TiledMap.class);
        Utils.Log("diagnostics", manager.getDiagnostics ());
        Utils.Log("assetnames", String.join(",",manager.getAssetNames ()));
```

And rendering with

```
camera.update();
renderer.setView(camera);
renderer.render();
```

Does anyone know why i can see the map and the normal tileset but none of the single image/object layer tilesets even though they seem to be loaded?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it looks like OrthogonalTiledMapRenderer doesn't implement rendering objects

I've created my own class, implemented rendering and i can see my object textures now

I've changed my renderer initialization to my new class

```
renderer = new OrthogonalTiledMapRendererV2(map);
```

Extended version of OrthogonalTiledMapRenderer

```
import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Color;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.TextureRegion;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.glutils.ShapeRenderer;
import com.badlogic.gdx.maps.MapLayer;
import com.badlogic.gdx.maps.MapObject;
import com.badlogic.gdx.maps.objects.CircleMapObject;
import com.badlogic.gdx.maps.objects.EllipseMapObject;
import com.badlogic.gdx.maps.objects.PolygonMapObject;
import com.badlogic.gdx.maps.objects.PolylineMapObject;
import com.badlogic.gdx.maps.objects.RectangleMapObject;
import com.badlogic.gdx.maps.tiled.TiledMap;
import com.badlogic.gdx.maps.tiled.objects.TiledMapTileMapObject;
import com.badlogic.gdx.maps.tiled.renderers.OrthogonalTiledMapRenderer;
import com.badlogic.gdx.math.Circle;
import com.badlogic.gdx.math.Ellipse;
import com.badlogic.gdx.math.Polygon;
import com.badlogic.gdx.math.Polyline;
import com.badlogic.gdx.math.Rectangle;

public class OrthogonalTiledMapRendererV2 extends OrthogonalTiledMapRenderer
{
    private ShapeRenderer shapeRenderer;

    public OrthogonalTiledMapRendererV2(TiledMap map)
    {
        super(map);

        shapeRenderer = new ShapeRenderer();
    }

    @Override
    public void renderObjects(MapLayer layer)
    {
        shapeRenderer.setProjectionMatrix(AppState.getInstance().camera.combined);
        shapeRenderer.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        Gdx.gl20.glLineWidth(2);

        super.renderObjects(layer);
    }

    @Override
    public void renderObject(MapObject mapObject)
    {
        if (mapObject.isVisible())
        {
            if (mapObject instanceof TiledMapTileMapObject)
            {
                TiledMapTileMapObject tmtObject = (TiledMapTileMapObject)mapObject;
                TextureRegion textureRegion = tmtObject.getTile().getTextureRegion();
                // TilEd rotation is clockwise, we need counter-clockwise.
                float rotation = -tmtObject.getRotation();
                float scaleX = tmtObject.getScaleX();
                float scaleY = tmtObject.getScaleY();
                float xPos = tmtObject.getX();
                float yPos = tmtObject.getY();
                textureRegion.flip(tmtObject.isFlipHorizontally(), tmtObject.isFlipVertically());
                batch.draw(textureRegion, xPos, yPos, tmtObject.getOriginX() * scaleX, tmtObject.getOriginY() * scaleY,
                        textureRegion.getRegionWidth() * scaleX, textureRegion.getRegionHeight() * scaleY, 1f, 1f, rotation);
                // We flip back to the original state.
                textureRegion.flip(tmtObject.isFlipHorizontally(), tmtObject.isFlipVertically());
            }
            else if (mapObject instanceof EllipseMapObject)
            {
                shapeRenderer.begin(ShapeRenderer.ShapeType.Filled);
                Ellipse ellipse = ((EllipseMapObject)mapObject).getEllipse();
                shapeRenderer.ellipse(ellipse.x, ellipse.y, ellipse.width, ellipse.height);
                shapeRenderer.end();
            }
            else if (mapObject instanceof CircleMapObject)
            {
                shapeRenderer.begin(ShapeRenderer.ShapeType.Filled);
                Circle circle = ((CircleMapObject)mapObject).getCircle();
                shapeRenderer.circle(circle.x, circle.y, circle.radius);
                shapeRenderer.end();
            }
            else if (mapObject instanceof RectangleMapObject)
            {
                shapeRenderer.begin(ShapeRenderer.ShapeType.Filled);
                Rectangle rectangle = ((RectangleMapObject)mapObject).getRectangle();
                shapeRenderer.rect(rectangle.x, rectangle.y, rectangle.width, rectangle.height);
                shapeRenderer.end();
            }
            else if (mapObject instanceof PolygonMapObject)
            {
                shapeRenderer.begin(ShapeRenderer.ShapeType.Line);
                Polygon polygon = ((PolygonMapObject)mapObject).getPolygon();
                shapeRenderer.polygon(polygon.getTransformedVertices());
                shapeRenderer.end();
            }
            else if (mapObject instanceof PolylineMapObject)
            {
                shapeRenderer.begin(ShapeRenderer.ShapeType.Line);
                Polyline polyline = ((PolylineMapObject)mapObject).getPolyline();
                shapeRenderer.polyline(polyline.getTransformedVertices());
                shapeRenderer.end();
            }
        }
        super.renderObject(mapObject);
    }
}
```

This is modified code from a test for libgdx from [here](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/tests/gdx-tests/src/com/badlogic/gdx/tests/TiledMapObjectLoadingTest.java)